# Any better way to find entry in table in a table?

Tags: python

Here's my code, can I do it better/faster?

```
phoneFound = False
    for host in nm.all_hosts():
            if 'mac' in nm[host]['addresses']:
                    if nm[host]['addresses']['mac'] == phone_mac:
                            phoneFound = True
    if phoneFound == False:
            print 'sh'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break out of the loop as soon as you found one. Alternatively (and better) you could do this in one line using the built-in function `any`, like so:

```
phone_found = any(nm[host]['address'].get('mac', None) == phone_mac for host in nm.all_hosts())
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like this way, it's much cleaner. I will accept your answer in 4 minutes